# Android App custom Number Picker

Tags: java, android

So I'm currently making an app that requires number pickers. I have create the number picker using a -button textview +button layout. tThe picker works fine apart from when you delete the number and try and press any of the buttons, at this point the application crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button btnUp, btnDown;
EditText editTextSonyResult;

int nStart = (-100);
int nEnd = 250;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusButton1);
    btnDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minusButton1);


    editTextSonyResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberView1);

    editTextSonyResult.setText("0");

    btnUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDown.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    String getString = String.valueOf(editTextSonyResult.getText());
    int current = Integer.parseInt(getString);


    if (v == btnUp) {
        if (current < nEnd) {

            current++;
            editTextSonyResult.setText(String.valueOf(current));
        }

    }
    if (v == btnDown) {
        if (current > nStart) {

            current--;
            editTextSonyResult.setText(String.valueOf(current));

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

here is the logcat at the point of the error
04-27 19:58:10.042    3016-3016/com.example.liam.sonyreportingapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-27 19:58:10.042    3016-3016/com.example.liam.sonyreportingapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.liam.sonyreportingapp, PID: 3016
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at com.example.liam.sonyreportingapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: your current becomes null.. that is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, here's an alternative to the existing answer, some time ago I made a custom NumberPicker class that you can simply add to your layout xml file:

[Custom NumberPicker class on github](https://gist.github.com/Regenhardt/73fe9e679985ec3d7dda)

Answer (score 1):

EditText will allow the user to manually make entries. If you do not want users to have this ability then switch to a TextView instead.

It's crashing on your

```
int current = parseInt(getString);
```

because if your EditText is empty because a user cleared the box then parseInt will return NaN (not a number) which cannot be stored as an int so it crashes.

Edit: Here is what it might look like to handle when they close the android keyboard but left the entry blank, dont forget to check for non-numeric entries too not just blank ones..

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberView1)).setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    //CHECK USER INPUT HERE. IF BLANK SET BACK TO 0 or DO NOT UPDATE VALUE ETC
                return true;
            }
            //I think this is if user presses back instead of pressing done/ok but i've never added code here
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Then add

```
android:imeActionId="@+id/IME_ACTION_SEND"
```

inside the EditText in your XML

Edit: removed questions.

Also, should the btnDown check for current > nEnd, instead of less than? Or current < nStart. I don't believe you want the exact same check for both.

Comment: Sorry I got my naming conventions wrong. Its actually an Edit text so the user can change it manually. I have since changed the <nEnd as it was supposed to be nStart

Comment: Ok yea EditText will let them change it. I think the root of this is ParseInt returning NaN - can confirm with your stack trace. If you want to allow user to edit the field manually (without your buttons) see my edit with the code for the input manager (android keyboard)

Comment: Yea, just as I suspected. Look at the 5th and 6th line of the stack trace you posted. Just add some code somewhere to check for what the user entered. If it's blank or something non numeric then you need to handle that before updating your current variable with parseint

Comment: I did not downvote you. But, I'm pretty sure that you should not ask questions in an answer.

Comment: Ah thanks, that fair and that makes sense Luis, unfortunately I cannot make comments yet so it limits my interaction with the OP to get more information without posting in the answer section. My original response did include the correct solution even before the stacktrace was posted AND identified the discrepancies in the language being used. Anyways thanks I appreciate the info, just wish the downvoter would say that instead of saying nothing :/